# URLEncode for HTML::link in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am setting up a blog in Laravel and cannot seem to figure out how to generate escaped URLs with `HTML::link(..)`. For example, I have links to different categories in the Blog such as Department News, I am trying to get a link formatted like so - `http://localhost/blog/category/department+news`., where `Department News` is generated by `$post->category`

I have tried the following code and it produces `http://localhost/blog/Department News`

```
{{ HTML::link('admin/blog/category/' . $post->category, $post->category) }}
```

How can I escape this and generate the desired URL?

Comment: Just change the `entities()` in html.php in the laravel folder, to suit your needs. Add the escaping url function there and it'l get implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, you'd have each post category use  a `slug` column in the database for the URL fragment, and then use something like:

```
HTML::link('blog/category/'.$post->category->slug, $post->category->name)
```

There's appears to be no way with Laravel to automatically encode only certain parts of the URL, so you'd have to do it yourself:

```
HTML::link(
    'admin/blog/category/'.urlencode(strtolower($post->category)),
    $post->category
)
```

You might want to consider using the "slug" approach. You don't necessarily have to store it in the database, you could have your class generate it on the fly:

```
class Category {
    function slug() {
        return urlencode(strtolower($this->name));
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you're working with exactly, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: I'm not a Laravel user, but I checked the docs, saw nothing, then dug around the source code (chasing down loads of static methods for a while) and concluded there was no built-in feature for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I disagree with Wesley, this works...

If you used [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) the `Url::route('category_browse',[category])` call will encode the values. The second parameter in the route method allows mixed content. So if you have only one parameter in your route you can pass a single value, otherwise an array.

in twig ([TwigBridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge)) this is ...

```
{{ url_route('category_browse',[category]) }}
```

otherwise ([Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating)) it should be ...

```
{{ Url::route('category_browse',[category]) }}
```

and your names route should be like this ...

```
Route::any('/blog/category/{category}',
    array(
        /*'before'=>'auth_check', -- maybe add a pre-filter */
        'uses' =>'BlogController@category',
        'as' => 'category_browse'
    )
);
```

Comment: urlencoded slashes do not work in Laravel due to what I consider a bug. 

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4323 

This pull request will resolve that bug.