# Laravel Html::link giving escaped data?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have the following blade template in laravel

```
<h3>Category</h3>
<div class="leftBoxBody">
     <ul class="cat-link">
         @foreach($categories as $category)
            <li>{{Html::link('category/'.$category->id, $category->name)}}</li>
         @endforeach
     </ul>
</div>
```

But its being generated into raw text instead of html tags output:

[image: raw text]

Why is this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URLEncode for HTML::link in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200587/urlencode-for-htmllink-in-laravel)

Answer (score 4):

It is happening because of escaping. Try with -

```
{!! Html::link('category/'.$category->id, $category->name) !!}
```