# Unexpected end of JSON input when passing array from Laravel to React

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am trying to pass an array from Laravel to my React component which works fine as long as there are no spaces in the data. I have the following code:

Migration file:

```
...
$table->text('other');
```

Controller:

```
$listings = Listing::latest()->take(20)->get();
return view('listing.index', compact('listings '));
```

View (where I pass data to the React component):

```
<div data-listings={{ $listings }} id="Listings"></div>
```

Component:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        listings: JSON.parse(props.listings)
    }
}
```

The code works fine as long as the `other` column doesn't have any spaces. For example, it works if `other` equals `"testdata"` but if it equals `"test data"` with space then I get `Unexpected end of JSON` and I can see that the JSON just ends at `... "other" : "test` Does someone know why this is happening?

Comment: Would it be possible to share some sample data to work with? Or maybe a CodeSandbox sample replicating the issue?

Comment: @SiddAjmera Here is the sample data, I don't know how to setup Laraven and React on the website you mentioned:

Here is what it looks like without spaces:
`[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"other":"without-space"}]`

and here is what it looks like when I add a space to the "other" value:
`[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"other":"without`

Comment: Errr... It would be really helpful if you could create a sample [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) example replicating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely going to have to use urlencode to encode the data before it is passed into the blade view. Passing Urlencode Laravel:[URLEncode for HTML::link in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200587/urlencode-for-htmllink-in-laravel) This will convert spaces in your JSON file to %20.